# Please help understating this recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm currently reading a book called Think Python by Allen Downey and i stumbled in in a problem so I came here seeking your assistance in order to understand this code:

```
def draw(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 
  print("A", n)         
  draw(n-1)
  print("B", n) 
  draw(n-1)
  print("C", n) 
  
draw(2)
```

From what I know the result should be something like:

```
A 2
A 1
B 1
C 1
```

But when I run the code I get this:

```
A 2
A 1
B 1
C 1
B 2
A 1
B 1
C 1
C 2
```

I cant figure it out why the result is beyond:

```
C 1
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing *why* you expect it to print the first thing.  Why do you think your `draw(2)` call *won't* do `print('B', 2)` and `print('C', 2)`?

Comment: I guess the answer might be "recursion doesn't automatically cause the caller to return".  Or in other words "recursion isn't always tail recursion".

Comment: each call to the function will print A n, B n and C n (unless n is 0). So in the answer you will get the same number of A, B and C. The only question is in which order they will appear and with which value of n. It might be helpful for you to draw a tree in a paper and go line by line, so you know in which branch you code is at every moment. If you follow the code you will see why the order you re getting is what it is. Sometimes a pen and a paper might be your best friends.

Comment: there is no problem with your code. it outputs what is expected. if you want a different result, you have to explain it following the rules of [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First, Break the code till first loop and add additional print statements to understand the code flow.

```
  def draw(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 
  print("A", n)         
  draw(n-1)
  print("First (n-1)")
  print("B", n) 
#   draw(n-1)
#   print("Second Iter")
#   print("C", n) 
  
draw(2)
```

For above code, the flow is like:
n = 2
In first iteration,
n=2,
"A 2" (We will call this as p1)
Recursion started with n=2, thus calling same function with n=1,
Now we are in second iteration,
n=1, "A 1" then it will print next statement ("First (n-1)"), then "B 1". Now here second iteration ends.
Then we go back to milestone p1, where we have n =2
So, back to first iteration, where n=2 starts after p1,it will print the statement ("First (n-1)") and then "B 2"

Once you understand this flow, you can uncomment the next part to understand the recursion.

```
Output:
A 2
A 1
First (n-1)
B 1
First (n-1)
B 2
```